# javascript loop through array using as pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have the array:

```
array = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
```

I want to make it used as pattern by a loop like

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
```

that gets dynamically the values from the array index, so in this case my goal is to have:

```
one two three four one two three four one two
```

Comment: [`%` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) -> `var idx = i % array.length;`

Comment: Note: This wouldn't be infinite, as there is still an end. It's just repeating.

Comment: Are you ever wanting to exit the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an infinite loop just create one like this:

```
var num = 0;
while(true) {
    var element = array[num];
    if(num == array.length - 1) {
        num = 0;
     } else {
        num++;
     }

     //when you are done
     //break;
}
```

You would use the element variable as each string or element in the array. And when you are done, just call 'break'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like below, the index you want to get is `i % array.length` (code in JavaScript):

```
var array = ["One","Two","Three","Four"];
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var word = array[i % array.length];
  results.push(word);
  // console.log(word);
}

console.log('this is the result: ' + results);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the logic to print the output you are looking for

syntax you can vary with any language

```
var l=array.length
counter=0
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){

if(counter=l){
print array[counter]
counter=0
}
else
{
print array[counter]
counter=counter+1
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
    var limit = 10;
    var asarray = true;
    var newarray = concatArray(array, limit, asarray);

    function concatArray(array, limit, asarray) {
        var size = array.length, counter = 0, newarray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            i = (i === size) ? 0 : i;
            if (counter <= limit) {
                newarray.push(array[i]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return newarray = (asarray === true) ? newarray : newarray.join(" ");
    }
```

asarray =true

["One", "Two", "Three", "Four","One", "Two", "Three", "Four","One", "Two", "Three"]

asarray =false

One Two Three Four One Two Three Four One Two Three

Answer (score -1):

You can use the original Array to concat to itself as many times as you want without even changing the original one like this:

```
array.concat(array).concat(array).concat(array)
// ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
```

Also, you could use a function where you can pass the times you want the array to be repeated, this way you don't have to deal with all those `concat` calls.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function concatArray(array, times) {
  var result = [], i = 0;

  for ( ; i < times; i += 1) {
    result = result.concat(array);
  }

  return result;
}

concatArray(arr, 3); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Finally, if you would like to modify the resulting array to have a certain number of items, or filter them, or map them, or whatever, you could add a callback to your function.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function concatArray(array, times, cb) {
  var result = [], i = 0;
  for ( ; i < times; i += 1) {
    result = result.concat(array);
  }

  if (cb && typeof cb == 'function') {
    result = cb(result);
  }

  return result;
}

var final = concatArray(arr, 3, function(a) {
  return a.slice(0, 10);
});

console.log(final) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: you are not answering the question. question is about adding array values based on index in a simple loop. this is a typical overkilled that generates crazy slow websites.

Comment: This is a better approach and more complete, I'm giving a better option with more control and better chances to create reusable code

Comment: it s neither more complete nor gives better control.